# Is there any way to install "glue" in Mac OS Catalina?

Tags: r, r-glue

I am trying to install the glue lib in my MacOS Catalina - which does not support 32-bit apps.

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [glue.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glue’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/glue’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘glue’ had non-zero exit status
```

Is there any version 64-bit or alternative to it?

Comment: Can you add the line you use to install the package? It would also be useful to add you system specs with `Sys.info()` and `R.version`

Comment: HI Daniel, please be sure to provide *all* of the console output starting with the `install.packages` call, since the vital line is likely one or two lines before the first you posted.

Comment: What if you just do `install.packages("glue", type="binary")? What version of R are you running?

Comment: I am using R 3.6.3